# physically based lighting on custom SCNGeometry Node

Tags: swift, scenekit, scnnode, scngeometry

### Question

How do you define the material on a [custom geometry from vertex data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometry/1522803-init), so that it renders the same as 'typical' SCNNodes?

---

### Details

In this scene there are

- A directional light
- A red sphere using [physicallybased](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlightingmodelphysicallybased) lighting model
- A blue sphere using physicallybased lighting model
- A custom SCNGeometry using vertex data, using a physicallybased lighting model

The red and blue spheres render as I would expect. The two points / spheres in the custom geometry are black.

Why?

---

Here is the playgrond code:

Setting the scene

```swift
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import PlaygroundSupport


// create a scene view with an empty scene
var sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600))
var scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene = scene
sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.75, alpha: 1.0)
sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sceneView

let directionalLightNode: SCNNode = {
    let n = SCNNode()
    n.light = SCNLight()
    n.light!.type = SCNLight.LightType.directional
    n.light!.color = UIColor(white: 0.75, alpha: 1.0)
    return n
}()

directionalLightNode.simdPosition = simd_float3(0,5,0) // Above the scene
directionalLightNode.simdOrientation = simd_quatf(angle: -90 * Float.pi / 180.0, axis: simd_float3(1,0,0)) // pointing down

scene.rootNode.addChildNode(directionalLightNode)

// a camera
var cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
cameraNode.simdPosition = simd_float3(0,0,5)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
```

Adding the blue and red spheres

```swift
// ----------------------------------------------------
// Example creating SCNSphere Nodes directly

// Sphere 1
let sphere1 = SCNSphere(radius: 0.3)
let sphere1Material = SCNMaterial()
sphere1Material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
sphere1Material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
sphere1.materials = [sphere1Material]

let sphere1Node = SCNNode(geometry: sphere1)
sphere1Node.simdPosition = simd_float3(-2,0,0)

// Sphere2
let sphere2 = SCNSphere(radius: 0.3)
let sphere2Material = SCNMaterial()
sphere2Material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
sphere2Material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
sphere2.materials = [sphere2Material]

let sphere2Node = SCNNode(geometry: sphere2)
sphere2Node.simdPosition = simd_float3(-1,0,0)

scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere1Node)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere2Node)
```

[image]

Adding the custom SCNGeometry

```swift
// ----------------------------------------------------
// Example creating SCNGeometry using vertex data
struct Vertex {
    let x: Float
    let y: Float
    let z: Float
    let r: Float
    let g: Float
    let b: Float
}

let vertices: [Vertex] = [
    Vertex(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, r: 1.0, g: 0.0, b: 0.0),
    Vertex(x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, r: 0.0, g: 0.0, b: 1.0)
]

let vertexData = Data(
    bytes: vertices,
    count: MemoryLayout<Vertex>.size * vertices.count
)

let positionSource = SCNGeometrySource(
    data: vertexData,
    semantic: SCNGeometrySource.Semantic.vertex,
    vectorCount: vertices.count,
    usesFloatComponents: true,
    componentsPerVector: 3,
    bytesPerComponent: MemoryLayout<Float>.size,
    dataOffset: 0,
    dataStride: MemoryLayout<Vertex>.size
)
let colorSource = SCNGeometrySource(
    data: vertexData,
    semantic: SCNGeometrySource.Semantic.color,
    vectorCount: vertices.count,
    usesFloatComponents: true,
    componentsPerVector: 3,
    bytesPerComponent: MemoryLayout<Float>.size,
    dataOffset: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 3,
    dataStride: MemoryLayout<Vertex>.size
)

let elements = SCNGeometryElement(
    data: nil,
    primitiveType: .point,
    primitiveCount: vertices.count,
    bytesPerIndex: MemoryLayout<Int>.size
)
        
elements.pointSize = 100
elements.minimumPointScreenSpaceRadius = 100
elements.maximumPointScreenSpaceRadius = 100

let spheres = SCNGeometry(sources: [positionSource, colorSource], elements: [elements])
let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: spheres)

let sphereMaterial = SCNMaterial()
sphereMaterial.lightingModel = .physicallyBased

spheres.materials = [sphereMaterial]

sphereNode.simdPosition = simd_float3(0,0,0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
```

[image]

---

### Some Exploration

Adding `normals` now shows the colours, but in all directions (i.e, there's no shadow).

And I've added a black `SCNSphere()` and a 3rd point to my `VertexData`, both using the same RGB values, but the black in the `VertexData` object appears too 'light'

```swift
let vertices: [Vertex] = [
    Vertex(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, r: 1.0, g: 0.0, b: 0.0),
    Vertex(x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, r: 0.0, g: 0.0, b: 1.0),
    Vertex(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0, r: 0.07, g: 0.11, b: 0.12)
]

let vertexData = Data(
    bytes: vertices,
    count: MemoryLayout<Vertex>.size * vertices.count
)

let normals = Array(repeating: SCNVector3(1,1,1), count: vertices.count)
let normalSource = SCNGeometrySource(normals: normals)

///
///

let spheres = SCNGeometry(
    sources: [
        positionSource,
        normalSource,
        colorSource
    ],
    elements: [elements]
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometrysource), making a custom geometry takes 3 steps.

1. Create a `SCNGeometrySource` that contains the 3D shape's vertices.
2. Create a `SCNGeometryElement` that contains an array of indices, showing how the vertices connect.
3. Combine the `SCNGeometrySource` source and `SCNGeometryElement` into a `SCNGeometry`.

Let's start from **step 1.** You want your custom geometry to be a 3D shape, right? You only have 2 vertices, though.

```
let vertices: [Vertex] = [         /// what's `r`, `g`, `b` for btw? 
    Vertex(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, r: 1.0, g: 0.0, b: 0.0),
    Vertex(x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, r: 0.0, g: 0.0, b: 1.0)
]
```

This will form a line...

[image: Line from (0, 0, 0) to (1, 0, 0). Format: (X, Y, Z)]

A common way of making 3D shapes is from triangles. Let's add 2 more vertices to make a pyramid.

```
let vertices: [Vertex] = [
    Vertex(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, r: 1.0, g: 0.0, b: 0.0), /// vertex 0
    Vertex(x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, r: 0.0, g: 0.0, b: 1.0), /// vertex 1
    Vertex(x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: -0.5, r: 0.0, g: 0.0, b: 1.0), /// vertex 2
    Vertex(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0, r: 0.0, g: 0.0, b: 1.0), /// vertex 3
]
```

[image: Pyramid from (0, 0, 0) to (1, 0, 0) to (1, 0, -0.5) to (0, 1, 0)]

Now, we need to convert the vertices into something that SceneKit can handle. In your current code, you convert `vertices` into `Data`, then use the [`init(data:semantic:vectorCount:usesFloatComponents:componentsPerVector:bytesPerComponent:dataOffset:dataStride:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometrysource/1523320-init) initializer.

```
let vertexData = Data(
    bytes: vertices,
    count: MemoryLayout<Vertex>.size * vertices.count
)
let positionSource = SCNGeometrySource(
    data: vertexData,
    semantic: SCNGeometrySource.Semantic.vertex,
    vectorCount: vertices.count,
    usesFloatComponents: true,
    componentsPerVector: 3,
    bytesPerComponent: MemoryLayout<Float>.size,
    dataOffset: 0,
    dataStride: MemoryLayout<Vertex>.size
)
```

This is very advanced and complicated. It's way easier with [`init(vertices:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometrysource/2034708-init).

```
let verticesConverted = vertices.map { SCNVector3($0.x, $0.y, $0.z) } /// convert to `[SCNVector3]`
let positionSource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: verticesConverted)
```

Now that you've got the `SCNGeometrySource`, it's time for **step 2** — connecting the vertices via `SCNGeometryElement`. In your current code, you use [`init(data:primitiveType:primitiveCount:bytesPerIndex:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometryelement/1522615-init), then pass in `nil`...

```
let elements = SCNGeometryElement(
    data: nil,
    primitiveType: .point,
    primitiveCount: vertices.count,
    bytesPerIndex: MemoryLayout<Int>.size
)
```

If the data itself is `nil`, how will SceneKit know how to connect your vertices? But anyway, there's once again an easier initializer: [`init(indices:primitiveType:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometryelement/1523191-init). This takes in an array of [`FixedWidthInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger), each representing a ​vertex back in your `positionSource`.

So how is each vertex represented by a `FixedWidthInteger`? Well, remember how you passed in `verticesConverted`, an array of `SCNVector3`, to `positionSource`? SceneKit sees each `FixedWidthInteger` as an index and uses it access `verticesConverted`.

Since indices are always integers and positive, [`UInt16`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/uint16) should do fine (it conforms to `FixedWidthInteger`).

```
/// pairs of 3 indices, each representing a vertex
let indices: [UInt16] = [
   ​0, 1, 3, /// front triangle
   ​1, 2, 3, /// right triangle
   ​2, 0, 3, /// back triangle
   ​3, 0, 2, /// left triangle
   ​0, 2, 1 /// bottom triangle
]
let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .triangles)
```

The order here is very specific. By default, SceneKit only renders the front face of triangles, and in order to distinguish between the front and back, it relies on your ordering. The basic rule is: **counterclockwise** means front.

[image: Front triangle highlighted. Vertices are 0, 1, and 3, counterclockwise]

So to refer to the first triangle, you could say:

- ​0, 1, 3
- 1, 3, 0
- 3, 0, 1

All are fine. Finally, **step 3** is super simple. Just combine the `SCNGeometrySource` and `SCNGeometryElement`.

```
let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [positionSource], elements: [element])
```

And that's it! Now that both your `SCNGeometrySource` and `SCNGeometryElement` are set up correctly, `lightingModel` will work properly.

```
/// add some color
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.orange
material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
geometry.materials = [material]

/// add the node
let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

[image: Orange pyramid]

---

**Notes:**

- I noticed that you were trying to use 2 `SCNGeometrySource`s. The second one was to add color with `SCNGeometrySource.Semantic.color`, right? The simpler initializer that I used, [`init(vertices:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometrysource/2034708-init), defaults to [`.vertex`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometrysource/semantic/1522639-vertex). If you want per-vertex color or something, you'll probably need to go back to [`init(data:semantic:vectorCount:usesFloatComponents:componentsPerVector:bytesPerComponent:dataOffset:dataStride:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometrysource/1523320-init).
- Try `sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true` for some better lighting
- [Full demo playground here](https://github.com/aheze/CustomSCNGeometry)

---

## Edit: Single Vertex Sphere?

You shouldn't be using a single point to make a sphere. If you're going to do...

```
elements.pointSize = 100
elements.minimumPointScreenSpaceRadius = 100
elements.maximumPointScreenSpaceRadius = 100
```

... then a 2D Circle is going to be the best you can get.

[image: Blue and red circle]

That's because, according to the [`pointSize` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometryelement/2867479-pointsize):

> SceneKit can render each point as a **small 2D surface that always faces the camera**. By applying a texture or custom shader to that surface, you can efficiently render many small objects at once.

Since what's rendered is really just a circle that rotates to face you, `.physicallyBased` lighting won't work (`.constant` will, but that's it). It's better to make your sphere with many small triangles, like the pyramid in the above answer. This is also what Apple does with their built in geometry, including `SCNSphere`.

```
let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 1)
let sphereMaterial = SCNMaterial()
sphereMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.purple
sphereMaterial.fillMode = .lines /// add this to see the triangles
sphereMaterial.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
sphere.materials = [sphereMaterial]

let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
```

[image: Transparent sphere composed of many purple-bordered triangles]

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. I am using `primitiveType: .point`, because I want 'points', not triangles. My code correctly draws the points, but I don't know how to set the materials and lighting so they look like the two seprate `SCNSphere()` objects.

Comment: and in your comment you ask `/// what's `r`, `g`, `b` for btw? ` - those are the colours, used in the `.color semantic`.

Comment: @tospig edited my answer. Points aren't going to work for 3D shapes.

Comment: Thanks for the updated. The key, as you point out, is in the documentation to `pointSize`, where it only renders 2D surfaces.